# FREERTOS disassembly problem

Tags: freertos

I just started to learn FREERTOS with atmel studio.
At first, I tried to make the most simple code "toggling LED".
I can build solution of the code, but when I try to debug my code, it stops at disassembly file every time.
What is wrong with my code? I think this code can't enter the main function also.
I used 'ATSAMD21G18A' in 'MKR1300'

I stop this part in assembly code.
00001B68   push {r0, r1, r2, r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}

````
#include <asf.h>
#include <FreeRTOSConfig.h>
#include <FreeRTOS.h>
#include <task.h>
#include <io.h>


#define LED0 IOPORT_CREATE_PIN(IOPORT_PORTA, 20)
#define LED0_ACTIVE 1
#define LED0_INACTIVE 0


void vLED_ON(void *pvParameters)
{
    const TickType_t xDelay = pdMS_TO_TICKS(500);
    ioport_set_pin_dir(LED0,IOPORT_DIR_OUTPUT);
    
while(1)
    {
        ioport_set_pin_level(LED0,LED0_ACTIVE);
        vTaskDelay(xDelay);
        
    }
}

void vLED_OFF(void *pvParameters)
{
    const TickType_t xDelay = pdMS_TO_TICKS(500);

    while(1)
    {
        ioport_set_pin_level(LED0,!LED0_ACTIVE);
        vTaskDelay(xDelay);
        
    }
}

int main(void)
{    
    system_init();
    system_clock_init();
    ioport_init();
    
    // RTOS start 
    xTaskCreate(vLED_ON, "LED_ON",128,NULL,1,NULL);
    xTaskCreate(vLED_OFF, "LED_OFF",128,NULL,2,NULL);
    vTaskStartScheduler();
    while(1);
}

void vApplicationMallocFailedHook()
{
    while(1);
}

void vApplicationStackOverflowHook()
{
    while(1);
}
```
````

Comment: An RTOS may substantially complicate breakpoint type debugging.  To achieve any useful result here, you're going to have to be far more clear about the **actual issue** for which you are requesting help.

Comment: Welcome to the site. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and findings so far in considerable detail. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Comment: Thanks for a comment. But I don't understand clearly, so did you mean that i just try programming on device because it is not good to use breakpoint type debugging in RTOS?